# Taking screenshot from multiple URL's with Ashot and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ashot

I am trying to automate a test case where i have to take the screenshot of a particular screen that exists in different websites. Spcifically, i am trying to test if a particular checkbox is aligned or not.Below is what i have as my script, and i am using Ashot to take the screenshots.The scripts logs into the three systems,and click on the link i want to it to click, however there is only a single screen shot from the last URL vs a screen shot from every URL. Please help me explain how can i iterate the Ashot so that it will take a screenshot for every website instead of what it is doing right now. Essentialy all the steps are iterated except taking the screenshot, and i want the script to iterate through the screenshots as well.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;

public class checkboxAlignment {

    String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Work\\chromedriver.exe";
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String expected = null;
    public String actual = null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void launchBrowser() {
        System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();


    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLprovider")
    private void notePrice(String url) throws IOException {
        driver.get(url);
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='PWD']"));
        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
        email.sendKeys("xxx@xxx.com");
        password.sendKeys("xxx");
        submit.click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //click on the  PI tab
        driver.findElement(By.id("IDpi")).click();
       // This doesnot iterate, only one screenshot is taken by Ashot
        Screenshot fpScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
        ImageIO.write(fpScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("C://Users//dir//eclipse-workspace//someDir//screenshots//checkbox.jpg"));

    }

    @DataProvider(name = "URLprovider")
    private Object[][] getURLs() {
        return new Object[][] { { "http://www.someURL.com/A" }, { "http://www.someurl.com/B" },
                { "http://www.someurl.com/C" } };
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saving all the screenshot in the same file `checkbox.jpg`. That is why your previous screenshots are replaced by the last one. Try to name the file different for every screenshot. Also, save the screenshots with `.png` extension as that is the actual file type.

**Try this for saving the image:**

```
ImageIO.write(fpScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("C://Users//dir//eclipse-workspace//someDir//screenshots//checkbox-"+driver.getCurrentUrl()+".png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this

```
@Step("Захват страницы для хранилища")
    protected void capturePageToVault(String pageName, String url, int scrollTime) throws IOException {
        open(url);
        expected = capturePage(scrollTime);

        ImageIO.write(expected.getImage(), "png", expectedImg(pageName));

        attach = new FileInputStream(expectedImg(pageName));
        Allure.addAttachment("Exemplar", "image/png", attach, ".png");
        attach.close();
    }
```